What does /actuator/health really do?
I Googled for the answer to this question and did not find helpful information. I would like to know the inner workings of /actuator/health endpoint implemented by Spring Boot: what does it really do? does it work by checking every API endpoints of an application with HEAD method (which implies every endpoint should automatically support HEAD)? what does it mean to be "UP"?

No, it just checks all the health check beans (HealthIndicator and ReactiveHealthIndicator).
